# V8 dead code elimination based on a runtime const

Tags: javascript, optimization, v8

This is related to *[Is V8 capable of dead code elimination, based on the value of the `const`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047178/is-v8-capable-of-dead-code-elimination-based-on-the-value-of-the-const)* except instead of an exported `const`, I have the following JavaScript code:

```js
// ... a `state` object is available as well as `newKey` and `newVal` strings and `isEqual` boolean
const newObj = { ...state.obj, [newKey]: newVal };
return isEqual ? state : { ...state, obj: newObj };
```

Can a warmed-up V8 notice that `newObj` is only used when `isEqual` is false, and avoid allocating `newObj`?

> I know that if I absolutely wanted to avoid that needless `newObj` allocation I should just move it into the conditional (`isEqual ? state : {...state, obj: {...}}`) or allocate it conditional on `isEqual` (`const newObj = isEqual ? undefined : {...}`). I'd like to better understand whether V8 is even capable of this kind of dead code elimination based on *runtime* consts to better make the readability-performance tradeoff.
>
> (I know about profiling, premature optimization, etc., let's just assume that I have a good reason to avoid needless allocations in this part of my code.)

Comment: Why not (as you yourself suggested) simply write the code so that the object is only allocated when it needs to be? Relying on an optimizer to do work that you could easily do yourself is not the best practice.

Comment: Also note that the creation of `newObj` may involve side-effects from getter functions in the source object(s), so the optimizer may not be willing to avoid its creation.

Comment: @Pointy you're right of course but there are always differences among team members when it comes to where they fall in the performance-readability spectrum. So improving our mental model of when this kind of optimization is even feasible will help inform those preferences.

Comment: Couldn't you just [convert that ternary operator to an `if` block](https://tsplay.dev/WPMBew) which `return`s if `isEqual` is false? That would be both readable and performant.

Comment: @InSync yes :)! The goal is to improve mental models, but whether or not we are able to do that, of course we should try to resolve the tension between readability and performance by creative synthesis like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

In a quick test, the allocation of `newObj` is not pushed into the conditional branch. An object is unconditionally allocated, and only afterwards the `isEqual ?` decision is considered.

That said, personally I see no tradeoff between readability and performance in this particular situation. IMHO,

```
  if (isEqual) return state;
  return { ...state, obj: { ...state.obj, [newKey]: newVal } };
```

(optionally with an `else` if you like) would be both more readable and more performant.

FWIW, this whole question has nothing to do with "dead code elimination". There is no dead code here that could be eliminated. You're asking about moving an operation into a conditional branch. And I have no idea what you mean by "runtime const".

Comment: Thank you! You're 100% right, I'm incorrectly using "dead code elimination" to mean "automatically move this code to the conditional" (in my mind, I was thinking of it as, "if the condition isn't met, don't run this" and confused myself). And by "runtime const" I meant, in contrast to `DEBUG` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047178/is-v8-capable-of-dead-code-elimination-based-on-the-value-of-the-const which is a literal const, `isEqual` is also a const but only known at runtime.

Comment: And I'm super-grateful for the check in this particular case, but could I pick your brain a bit more: is V8 *capable* of doing this kind of runtime rewriting, i.e., moving code into conditionals and skipping running it when it's not needed? (I associate this more with compilers for lazy languages like Haskell and have no reliable understanding of whether V8 would/could do this.)

Comment: @AhmedFasih It depends. In some cases V8 can move operations into branches. But JavaScript is difficult to optimize, because many innocent-looking operations can have observable or compiler-assumption-perturbing side effects, so I wouldn't rely on that happening. E.g. anything that can throw or allocate or invalidate certain assumptions is unlikely or impossible to optimize out or move around.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying you should write unreadable code to accommodate engines' limitations -- on the contrary: the general recommendation is to _write code that makes sense_. That doesn't include "write code that looks like it's doing lots of heavy work, and hope that the JS engine can optimize that away".